# Using MMF (memory mapped file) as a logging

Tags: c, unix, logging, file-descriptor, memory-mapped-files

I have to use a memory mapped file to write down some data from the project i'm working in. Things like:

> -The PID of a process when it begins and when it ends
>
> -Whenever a thread is initialized and ended.

etc. But i can't figure out, with the very limited information i can find, how to do such a thing. I leave here my atempt at creating the log in question:

```
void create_log(){
  char *addr;
  struct stat sb;
  if((flog = open(LOG, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK)) < 0){
    perror("Couldn't open log for writing");
    exit(0);
  }
  if(fstat(flog, &sb) == -1){
    perror("fstat");
    close(flog);
    exit(0);
  }
  addr = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size,PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,flog,0);
}
```

if waiting for a functional example is to much to ask, i'd like at least a link to where i can find the information i need to learn. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using a memory mappep file for logging is a strange requirement. Anyway, you can only map an *open* file in memory, so you should at least say how you want to use it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta well my project requirements merely states that log has to be memory mapped, for performance reasons. It doesn't specify anything else. But i want to do like this: i have a (maybe) txt file that when the program is closing receives the info from the MMF.

Comment: Search for proc file system.

Comment: @Vagish to my understanding proc file system does, more or less, what i want, but i am required to use MMF to logging.